# Python:how to replace string by index

Tags: python

I am writing a program like unix tr, which can replace string of input.
My strategy is to find all indexes of source strings at first, and then replace them by target strings. I don't know how to replace string by index, so I just use the slice. 
However, if the length of target string doesn't equal to the source string, this program will be wrong. I want to know what's the way to replace string by index.

```
def tr(srcstr,dststr,string):
    indexes = list(find_all(string,srcstr)) #find all src indexes as list
    for index in indexes:
        string = string[:index]+dststr+string[index+len(srcstr):]
    print string
```

tr('aa','mm','aabbccaa')
the result of this will be right: mmbbccmm
but if tr('aa','ooo','aabbccaa'), the output will be wrong:

ooobbcoooa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strings are immutable (as far as I can remember), so you can't just go in and insert stuff.

Luckily Python already has a `replace()` function.

```
>>> s = "hello, world!"
>>> s1 = s.replace("l", "k")
>>> print s1
hekko, workd!
```

Comment: @remy Has your question been answered? If so, you can accept an answer using the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the str.replace method?  I think it will do what you're wanting:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace

And when you find that you're wanting to support more than simple string replacement, check out the re module:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

```
def tr(srctr, deststr, string):
    string = string.split(srctr)
    return ''.join([deststr if i == '' else i for i in string ])

print tr('aa', 'ooo', 'aabbccaa') # ooobbccooo
```